# How does the government pay for large purchases?

Tags: united-states, government, military, financing

What are the logistics of the government purchasing an aircraft carrier? ACH has a 9 digit limit for example. Do they enter 10 separate payments for a $10B aircraft carrier into Netsuite and click "pay"? What is the actual operational detail?

Comment: Does the government really purchase an aircraft carrier with one payment? I would have expected multiple contractors and progress payments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While terms will vary by government and specific contract, [progress payments](https://govcontractassoc.com/financing-your-contracts/) are the typical means for financing expensive, long-term government projects.

> Progress payments are periodic  payments made by the government as performance on the contract proceeds.  Such payments are based either on cost incurred by the contractor or on a percentage of stage of completion achieved under the contract.  Perfomance-based payments are contract financing payments of predetermined amounts that are made when a contractor satisfies predefined contract events or criteria.  They are not payments for accepted items but rather advances based  on work performed.

---

**Information specific to the United States.**

Briefly, the US Navy requests and Congress approves the construction of ships.

[This table](https://media.defense.gov/2009/Mar/26/2001711998/-1/-1/1/09-065.pdf#page=10) from an Inspector General's report shows ships under construction in 2009.

[image: Ships Under Construction]

Note that with a few exceptions, financing uses progress payments.

As the ships are built, various documents are submitted to the [Defense Finance Accounting Service (DFAS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_Finance_and_Accounting_Service).

Everything from the contracts to [contractor payments](https://www.dfas.mil/Portals/98/Documents/Contractors-Vendors/DIL_MOCAS-AP-Update.pdf?ver=2020-02-29-143109-110#page=21) are processed by the Mechanization Of Contract Administration Services (MOCAS) system.

[image: What is MOCAS?]

[image: High-Level MOCAS Processing]

[What Is the Oldest Computer Program Still in Use?](https://www.technologyreview.com/2015/08/06/166822/what-is-the-oldest-computer-program-still-in-use/), MIT Technology Review, August 6, 2015.

> Trillions of dollars have passed through the computational records in MOCAS. In its current form the system is managing roughly $1.3 trillion in obligations and 340,000 contracts.